# Non striker position in cricket

Tags: cricket

Before the ball is pitched by the bowler, could the non striker stand, on his ground, where they like? I mean I know he can not stand in pitching trajectory of bowler but could he stand, ie. his starting point on the crease line, whereever he likes? For example in the crease line in infield or even in outfield?